# The Task.leftShift(Closure) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use Task.doLast(Action) instead

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, ionic3

I have created an blank project and successfully build and run in my device

> but when i add this plugin `ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-geofence` and give `ionic cordova run android` i am getting the error as

i have not written any code

[image: below]

Comment: the real (origin) error is at the bottom. It seems that your plugin depends on a component that is not properly installed (license agreements not accepted)

Comment: ok how to accept the license agreement @Kaddath

Comment: sorry, i never encoutered this error, or i would have made a better answer. i just can point out what i see from the log. Note that it is quite common to have deprecation notices on compilation, depending on plugins you will install and versions

Comment: @MohanGopi by chance are you able to get out of this hurdle? i have same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You gotta open your Andoroid SDK Manager and install the following components as mentioned in the error:

1. SDK Patch Applier V4
2. Google repositoty
3. Android Support Library

Comment: @MohanGopi You gotta install the right version that the plugin is dependent on

Comment: ya i got the outpu i was missing my licence folder after adding that everything is working fine

Comment: @MohanGopi Ideally that gets added as part of the installation itself (atleast in windows). May be you would have missed out some steps during the install

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify, I changed my package.json to:

"cordova-android": "6.2.0",

which fixed the problem for me.

Comment: Also do below if not works :

go to ionic_folder/platforms/android/build.gradle

If you see this lines of code in your file

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }

    }
Change the order of the executions

  buildscript {
    repositories {

        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        jcenter()

    }
Then go again and run your application by doing ionic cordova run android

Answer (score 0):

```
go to ionic_folder/platforms/android/build.gradle

If you see this lines of code in your file

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }

    }
Change the order of the executions

  buildscript {
    repositories {

        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        jcenter()

    }
Then go again and run your application by doing ionic cordova run android
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the Package.json file

```
"cordova-android": "6.2.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

getting same problem in ionic 5 build and solved by running the following commands

```
cordova clean android
cordova plugin add cordova-android-support-gradle-release
```